# how to create a function in oracle for last_insert_id() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure in MySQL and I want to convert it into Oracle procedure, All is ok but MySQL inbuilt function "last_insert_id()" raise the error. Is there any solution to resolve it? Can i create a function for same in oracle.

```
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: Search for examples of `returning clause` in Oracle, check also this link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm

Comment: Oracle and MySQL internally works different. Approaches which are good for MySQL may be bad for Oracle. For what purpose do you want this function?

Comment: read about oracle sequences https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm i think it help you.

Comment: @EvgeniyK.: I have procedure in MySQL that I have converted it into Oracle procedure. I have usee last_insert_id() function in mysql but its raises the error. So I want to create a function in oracle that behave and return a value like mysql last_insert_id().

Comment: @АнатолийПредеин has already mentioned link to sequence. It might be helpful but in some cases it works not the same like in MySQl due to parallel sessions.

Comment: @EvgeniyK. you right, and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id give me, that it return last good ID inserted in table, but sequence.CURRVAL can give wrong value, because it may be called without insert in table. maybe topic starter want get simle max(id) from his_table :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do similar function in Oracle which works extactly as in MySQL correct me someone if I am wrong.

Look at this notes in MySQL doc(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

> For stored functions and triggers that change the value, the value is
>   restored when the function or trigger ends, so following statements
>   will not see a changed value.
>
> Important
>
> If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement,
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted
>   row only. The reason for this is to make it possible to reproduce
>   easily the same INSERT statement against some other server.

In Oracle autoincrement column works since 12c and they're based on sequence. If someone calls sequence.NextVal then all sessions will see only changed values of sequence. In MySQL behavior is diffrent(look again on Important note)

Oracle and MySQL works different especially when parallel sessions works.

Answer (score 0):

@krokodilko and @NicholasKrasnov tell you how can be used returning clause.

my example, if you want get ID of just now inserted row:

```
declare
 l_id number;
begin
-- ONE ROW INSERT
l_id := someseq.nextval;
begin
  insert into temp(id) values(l_id);
 -- if insert fail then variable must be null
 exception when others then l_id := null ;
end;

if l_id is not null then 
  -- do what you want RETURN this, or use for other statements
  null;
  -- here you have just now inserted ID in variable l_id
end if;

-- MULTIPLE INSERT

for some_data in (select * from some_joined_tables) loop

  l_id := someseq.nextval;

  begin
    insert into temp(id) values(l_id);
   exception when others then l_id := null ;
  end;

  if l_id is not null then 
    -- do what you want RETURN this, or use for other statements
    -- here you have just now inserted ID in variable l_id
  end if;

end loop;

-- HERE (after loop) YOU CAN RETURN LAST INSERTED VALUE of current transaction in variable l_id

end;
```

it's just demo of code and i'am not compiling it on server